# Should the tag wi-fi be a synonym of wireless?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I think so.  This question is just a way to get a consensus/vote on the thing.

wifi is already duped to wireless and wi-fi is just another spelling of wifi.

Comment: Moderators can merge and create synonyms without a question in the tag.

Comment: I suppose someone re-tagged it away last night.  I made the question related to something in chat last night

Comment: Please just feel free to propose a synonym [directly on the tag](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wireless/synonyms) instead.

Comment: will do in the future

Answer (score 11):

### Yes

- There is no difference in the two tags
- Wifi seems more standard
- Duplicate tags based on spelling differences only confuse the thing
- The fellow that brought it up in chat should add at least one reason ;)